# How can I find all the files that my GoPro contains?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, sd-card, gopro

I connected my GoPro Hero 10 via USB to my Win10 laptop. There is a 512 GB SD card (~= 477 GiB) in the GoPro Hero 10. Windows Explorer shows that out of the 477 GiB, only 10.6 GiB are free (i.e, 477-10.6=466.4GiB is used):

[image]

However, the `100GOPRO` folder only contains 318 GiB of files:

[image]

And the only other two files outside the `100GOPRO` folder are just 8 and 139 bytes:

[image]

[image]

This means there exist 466.4 GiB - 318 GiB = 159.4 GiB of files don't appear in Windows Explorer. How can I find these invisible files?

I believe that Windows Explorer is correct to say that only 10.6 GiB is free, as my GoPro also indicates the SD is low on free space (based on the estimate of how many minutes of recordings I can do with the SD).

I tried another file manager, Total Commander, and it agrees with Windows Explorer that the `100GOPRO` folder only contains 318 GiB of files:

[image]

Hidden files are displayed:

[image]

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks, as you can see on https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFFs1.png there are only 312 files, so that doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: Are you able to try using an SD Card reader port or adapter instead of connecting the GoPro directly with a USB to see if the files then become visible?

Comment: @DrZoo thanks, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another SD adapter, turns out that the GoPro only lists the DCIM folder, but the SD had other folders too:

[image]

Thanks [OkMany3232](https://www.reddit.com/user/OkMany3232) and [DrZoo](https://superuser.com/users/482362/drzoo) for the idea.

Comment: Devices that use `MTP` have very limited functionality compared to e.g. FAT/VFAT. MTP = Media Transfer Protocol -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol . Another similar "thing" is `PTP` -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol