# Why does the file size of the a being transferred depends on how much free space the external hard drive has, and how can I avoid that?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, size

I transfer some files from a GoPro (connected via MTP) to an external hard drive. I notice that for the file size of the file being transferred depends on how much free space the external hard drive has. Why, and how can I avoid that?

E.g. `GX040190.MP4` in the screenshot below is being transferred and takes 231 GB on the target hard drive while it's being transfered, and the free space available on the external hard drive before the transfer is ~244 GB:

[image]

even though the file size itself before or after the transfer is only ~3.9GB:

[image]

Available disk space on the external hard drive before the transfer:

[image]

That's an issue for me when transferring several files, because no matter how much space I free on the hard drive, I keep getting some insufficient disk space error after transfer a few files. This is because the file size of the file being transferred is just a few GBs fewer than the free space the external hard drive has at the beginning of the transfer (and if I transfer e.g. 20 files, it'll consider the free space that the external hard drive had at the beginning of the 1st file transfer, and not free space that the external hard drive had at the beginning of the current file transfer):

[image]

I use Windows 10.

Comment: This reeks of filesystem corruption and/or problems with MTP, which is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: So your question is 'why'. It's obviously wrong so I wonder if there's a logical answer to 'why' other than this being a bug.

Comment: Instead of MTP, take out memory card, and use memory card reader to transfer files to PC.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen thanks, my memory card reader is ~4 times slower than my GoPro, and since I'm transferring ~200 GB, using my memory card reader adds about ~1 day of transfer time. But yes, point taken, maybe use a better memory card reader. Currently I just retry the batch file transfer several times (this way, the free space that the external hard drive had at the beginning of the 1st file transfer gets lower each  time I retry the batch file transfer). But it's rather stupid and I have to monitor.

Comment: Perhaps (long shot) an alternative explorer solves it? Like Total Commander or something? I agree it is rather stupid BTW.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Good point, maybe indeed, I'll let you know if I try.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, is that MTP protocol makes Windows Explorer dependent on what the connected device reports. IOW, where in case of for example a USB storage device, Windows has access at the block or file system level, MTP protocol does not allow for this.

So, again the USB storage device as an example, Windows Explorer can *itself* determine file sizes, just like it can with local hard drives where in case of the MTP protocol it's almost as if it's communicating over a network protocol where the 'other party' determines a file size and communicates this to the 'client'.

So MTP is almost more like a 'communication protocol' than a 'storage protocol'.

MTP adds an abstraction layer where Windows can only query the file size and has to rely on the MTP protocol. If an incorrect size is reported there's not a lot Windows Explorer can do.

> MTP is a high level file transfer protocol, as opposed to a general
> storage protocol like USB mass storage. That means that the MTP client
> (computer) does not see an array of byte blocks that makes up a data
> structure that makes up a file system, but instead speaks in terms of
> files and folders to the MTP device. This lets the MTP device take
> part in the high level operations (such as updating its metadata
> indexes) while keeping the integrity of its file system in its own
> hands

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol

If my earlier suggestion in the comments of using an alternative File Explorer fixes the issue for you it seems that the bug is within Windows Explorer. If you run into the same issue it's more likely we can not blame Windows Explorer.

Your best option though is using a good card reader. MTP protocol is a very hampered protocol as was illustrated by your [earlier topic](https://superuser.com/q/1786239/705502).